# Rubymotion organize resources in subfolders

Tags: rubymotion

When I use subfolders in ./resources directory I can't get access to them.
What is the correct way to organise properly the resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you reference the subfolder in your code. If your image is `./resources/subfolder/imagename.png`, do this:

```
image = UIImage.imageNamed("subfolder/imagename")
```

That works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me for an OSX app. What works:

```
# Rakefile
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.resources_dirs << ['resources/icons']
end
```

Accessing files

```
image = UIImage.imageNamed("imagename") # icons subfolder not needed
```

Comment: resources_dirs didn't exist when the question was asked :D